# ClassList.toggle not working inside an ul (HTML/CSS/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, html-lists

So I'm quite new to JavaScript and I'm trying to make a dropdown navigation bar for mobile devices.

```js
let mainNav = document.getElementById('js-menu');
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');

navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {

    mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
});

let dropdownNav = document.getElementById('js-dropdown-menu');
let dropdownToggle = document.getElementById('js-dropdown-toggle');

dropdownToggle.addEventListener('click', function () {

    dropdownNav.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900i|Roboto:900|Roboto:700|Roboto:300&display=swap";

:root {
  --primary-color: #518985;
  --navbar-bg-color: #F2F2F2;
  --header-text-color: #000000;
  /*--text-color-1: #F2F2F2;*/
  /*--text-color-2: #000000;*/

  /*--header-height: 75px;*/
  /*--header-dropdown-tab-height: 50px;*/

  --logo-font: Lato, sans-serif;

  --tab-font: Roboto, sans-serif;
  --tab-font-weight: 300;
  --tab-font-size: 15px;

  /*--dropdown-tab-font-weight: 700;*/
  --dropdown-tab-font-size: 13px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.navbar {
  background: var(--navbar-bg-color);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 22px;

  font-family: var(--logo-font);
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}

.logo-letter-accent-color {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.logo-letter-text-color {
  color: var(--header-text-color);
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-link, .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font-family: var(--tab-font);
  font-family: var(--tab-font-weight);
  font-size: var(--tab-font-size);
}

.nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-link {
  padding-left: 30px;
  font-size: var(--dropdown-tab-font-size);
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  float: right;
}

#selected-tab {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6a2f31ed4f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header_mobile.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Start Nav -->
    <nav class="navbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </span>
      <a class="logo" href="#">
        <span class="logo-letter-accent-color">J</span><span class="logo-letter-text-color">D</span><span class="logo-letter-text-color">L</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
        <li><a id="selected-tab" class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Leben</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Interessen</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" id="js-dropdown-toggle" href="#">Background<span class="dropdown-toggle">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </span></a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown" id="js-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-link" href="#">Qualifikation</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-link" href="#">Referenzen</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Nav -->

    <div class="page-wrapper">

    </div>

    <script src="header.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

For that I need two JavaScript actions: One for the main-nav to display and one for the dropdown to display. The first one works fine. The second one however, although both actions are kind of the same, doesn't work.

I've tested around a little bit and found out that the problem has to do with the classList.toggle function addressing an id or class inside the first ul, because the function works just fine with everything outside the ul.

I'd really appreciate somebody helping me out since I nor can't figure it out by myself neither find a solution for it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with css and specificity.

If you declare a class `.nav-dropdown.active {display:block}` it will work correctly. The thing is `.active` and `.nav-dropdown` have the same specificity and since the `.nav-dropdown` is declared after `.active` it will always prevail.

The solution I posted creates a selector of higher specificity to overcome the problem (which will supersede the order).

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to figure it out for more than a hour and the solution is so simple. Thanks!

Comment: no worries, I had similar problems when starting with css, Here is a good read on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity